# Switching from plugin to gem -- issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

What, if any, issues can you expect to encounter if you replace plugin with a gem version?  For ex, paperclip plugin to paperclip gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issue. It's exact same thing but better. If you plugin can be a gem.